# Continuously (asynchronously) poll and update label in C++ GUI application

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I have an application that opens another process and modifies its memory. What I'd like to have as a part of the GUI is a label that updates (perhaps every second or so) to let the user know if they're attached to the other process.

When the application is found running, I'm creating a handle to it, obtaining the base address of it, and then the rest of the work is done through button clicks and hotkeys. Anyway, for each time the application is found running, I want it to do all the things I have it do to obtain the handle, etc., etc.

This way, the other application can be closed and reopened without my app also needing to be closed/reopened accordingly.

Thus far, my research has led me to [CreateThread()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx) and [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) (as well as std::launch::async and std::launch::deferred). The issue I'm having is I can't seem to find examples of infinitely-running asynchronous code (in its own thread, perhaps). I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around how to make this happen, as everything I've tried still keeps execution from continuing as if I'd just written a while loop in main() or something.

Anything exemplifying the type of functionality I'm looking to achieve would be immensely appreciated! Thanks for your time and help, everyone.

Comment: You probably don't need a thread _or_ an async task. You need to post a repeating event to your UI looper, and when you receive the event, you update that part.  What's your UI toolkit?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mooing Duck. I'm looking to keep this application as lightweight as possible, so I'm using the Win32 API.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx